# Using HTML ID as arrays

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select class="dName" name="dName">
    <option SELECTED value="#" DISABLED>========================</option>
    <option id="0" value="amensah">Abbey-Mensah, Michael</option>
    <option id="1" value="acharya">Acharya, Niraj</option>
    <option id="2" value="achonu">Achonu, Geoffrey C.</option>
    <option id="3" value="agustin">Agustin, Erie</option>
    <option id="4" value="agyemang">Agyemang, Kuragu</option>
</select>
```

I am using the ID in my Javascript:

```
if (i[iVar] == $(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')) {
```

To pull which option was selected.

Now let's say I want to delete options #2 for the **dName** select, instead of changing the #3 to #2 as ID and #4 to #3 as ID, can I use an array? This might be easy but having a 100+ options would make it really time consuming

Is there anyway to change the ID in the dName select so no matter what it is used as an array? Something like:

```
<option id="[]" value="amensah">Abbey-Mensah, Michael</option>
```

So if I delete an option in the middle of the list, it will keep the numbering structure in order?

**RESOLVED**:

```
if (i[iVar] == $(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')) {
```

Has been changed to:

```
if (i[iVar] == "the value of selection option") {
```

**AND**

```
document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')].firstName;
```

Has been changed to:

```
document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').index()-1].firstName; //.index()-1 because the first option is "=" which is not being used
```

So I can completely get rid of the ID and not worry about deleting an option statement.

Comment: Than you actually don't need ID at all, but rather grab the `index` of your element on change.

Comment: the id attribute might not be the right attribute to use for this.

Comment: The way you are doing it, no. it won't maintain the numbering structure by itself. Why can't you use the `value` as the unique identifier, and if you wanted to access which index the option is, you can use jQuery

Comment: hey buddy you dont need the Id for each option to know the selected option.`$('select[class]=dName option:selected')` this way you can get the selected option

Comment: This is my page: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/search.htm (how would i use the INDEX to achieve it in my JavaScript code?)

Comment: My JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/6JV4u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need IDs at all, whatever you delete (**.remove() ?**) in your `select` element take the `index` of the selected `option`:

**just for example:**

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
  alert( $(':selected').index() );
});
```

http://jsbin.com/akefaq/2/edit

Comment: Is it possible to look at the code: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/search.htm and let me know if i remove the .attr('id'); in my codes will it still work?

Comment: @SiKni8 why don't you test my suggestion?

Comment: Your suggestion would work perfect I know... I am just confused as to where to make the changes in my Javascript code to allow index to come in handy :|

Comment: Can i use the VALUE? instead so no matter where the name is located, it would pull up based on that?

Comment: @SiKni8 you build your script in a very strange way. I would suggest you to store your values into `var` instead or reusing them all over the code. It's really messy. All you need could be written in a couple of lines.

Comment: "document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')].firstName;" this is where the ID comes into play.